# SP2013 remove server cacheHostInfo null and no access to old server

Tags: 2013, powershell, sharepoint-server, distributedcache

I had a server, SHPprod, but it did not match the naming scheme that I am using, SHPprodWFE. I removed it from the farm using the config wizard. Renamed the computer to be SHPprodWFE and added it back into the farm. When I had configured it properly I checked the SP Health Analyzer only for there to be issues related to the old server specific to the Distributed Cache.

In centraladmin > services I am able to change my view to be the old server and the only thing I see if Distributed Cache Stopped". If I go into centraladmin > Manage Servers I see the old server and it is labeled as "Not Configured" and I try to remove the server only to get "cacheHostInfo is null".

How can I remove a server that does not exist from Distributed cache so that I can del

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this guide that helped me remove it. http://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/cacheHostInfo-is-null-removing-server-from-SharePoint-2013#.U2ziEfldUrY

With the following PowerShell code,

```
$SPFarm = Get-SPFarm
$cacheClusterName = "SPDistributedCacheCluster_" + $SPFarm.Id.ToString()
$cacheClusterManager = [Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.Utilities.SPDistributedCacheClusterInfoManager]::Local
$cacheClusterInfo = $cacheClusterManager.GetSPDistributedCacheClusterInfo($cacheClusterName);
$instanceName ="SPDistributedCacheService Name=AppFabricCachingService"
$serviceInstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | ? {($_.Service.Tostring()) -eq $instanceName -and ($_.Server.Name) -eq "Server name for server you are trying to remove"}
$serviceInstance.Delete()
```

Comment: Could you mark this as the accepted answer, and it may help others in the future? Thank you!